# Where should I unregister events in XAML Behavior?

Tags: xaml, uwp, behavior

In a XAML behavior class, where should be the best place to unregister events? Should I unregister it in **Unloaded** event or should I do it while **Deteching**?

```
  public class ShowKeyboardOnFocusBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
  {

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
      base.OnAttached();
      AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
      AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
      AssociatedObject.Unloaded += AssociatedObject_Unloaded;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
      AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
      AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= AssociatedObject_Unloaded; 
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
      AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
      AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `OnDetaching` to unregister your events. This method will always be called and it is the approach used in the official UWP Behaviors library from Microsoft (see [for example EventTriggerBehavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/master/src/BehaviorsSDKManaged/Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions/Core/EventTriggerBehavior.cs)).

It used to be an issue (that the associated object got unloaded but behaviors stayed in memory) but it is now accounted for right within the library, so you know for sure `Detach` will be called (you can see it yourself in the `FrameworkElement_Unloaded` method in [`Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction` source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/b49d3ddb42d7f947fe0842d27a50ab4cd28450ef/src/BehaviorsSDKManaged/Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity/Interaction.cs))